# Error in releasing pool connection in node project

Tags: node.js, connection, mysql-workbench

[My code for executing queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2YcG.png)

var mysql = require('mysql');
const connectionPool = mysql.createPool(process.env.DATABASE_CREDENTIALS);

```
export default async function executeQuery({ query, values }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connectionPool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
        // Release the connection back to the pool (if obtained)
        if (connection) connection.destroy();
        return reject(err);
      } else {
        connection.query(query, values, (err, results) => {
          // Release the connection back to the pool
          connection.destroy();
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          } else {
            // console.log(results);
            resolve(results);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I execute my queries through this and I observed that after every query the process goes in sleep and not releases. One of the processes is like this:

## Id, User, Host, db, Command, Time, State, Info

189, root, localhost:49214, erp_software_db, Sleep, 1334, ,

After I close the connection manually, all the processes are killed but on restarting the id continues from where it was left and not 1.

But after certain time many processes are just accumulated and I get an error saying "Too many connections".

Can anyone guide me through this??  Thanks for your replies in advance.

Just now I tried using connection.destroy() instead of connection.release(), and this seems to help but I am not sure since for first few attempts it worked and for a moment it didn't. So kindly do explain this too as is it a good choice to use or not ?

Comment: Your code is a client. MySQL Workbench is another client. There is no 'connection between' them. Both have connections to the MySQL server, and none to each other. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, but if you did understand kindly provide a solution to it. Thank you

Comment: I *don't* understand. That's why I asked you to clarify your question.

Comment: Sure. I have a node project and a sql database and to perform any operations in the database through my project I use the above shared code(in image), but this code leaves the connections just simply instead of releasing them though I am trying to. And these connections pile up which leads to "Too many connections Error ". Can you please rectify the code ?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)